# viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" not encrypting

Tags: asp.net, encryption, iis-6, viewstate, cassini

Due to some security concerns i need to enable View State Encryption.  I have viewstate & viewstateMAC turned off but i need to encrypt the "[control state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/site/ms178199)" string that is included in the __VIEWSTATE form parameter.

Currently my web.config looks like:

```
    <pages enableViewState="false" enableViewStateMac="false">
```

When i set the following, in cassini, my viewstate is encrypted:

```
    <pages enableViewState="false" enableViewStateMac="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
```

When i make the same change on my IIS 6  server, nothing happens.

I see the app domain recycle(Event: Application '/LM/W3SVC/...' located in 'C:...' initialized for domain '...'). when i touch web.config but i do not get encrypted viewstate as with cassini. I have tried Site Stop/Start, IIS Reset Stop/Start, Clear ASP.NET Temporary file cache.  Anyone have any suggestions on what needs to be done to configure this?

Comment: ( i have asked this [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598199/asp-net-viewstate-encryption-issue) but the post got a bit too detailed... this is simplified as i am revisiting the issue!)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since security is a concern, you should not set `enableViewStateMac` to `false`, and you should use the `ViewStateUserKey` property, to pretect you from CSRF attacks (which can happen even with an encrypted view state). Or even better, use this plugin: http://anticsrf.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Why do you have enableViewState set to false???

Comment: I don't need it.. I have a custom built handler the acts as MVC on top of ASP.NET.  Either way, so i changed my web.config to this and it still isn't encrypting:  <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with this and it came down to the fact that if you pre-compile your site the web.config node for pages is ignored.  You have to set those settings at compile to get it working.  I know this is year late, but I figure if someone else comes here looking for solution to the problem this might be useful information.

A little blurb about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/07/19/pages-settings-don-t-work-for-pre-compiled-asp-net-applications.aspx

- (Link dead - blog pointed to this documentation: [ASP.NET Web Site Project Precompilation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx) )
- > My customer had a viewstate MAC
  >   validation problem. As a workaround, he wanted to disable the
  >   viewstate MAC validation before find out the final solution. However,
  >   he was still seeing the problems after added follow settings in the
  >   configuration files.
  >
  > Customer’s application is a pre-compiled ASP.Net application with
  >   updatable option disabled. Looking at the code generated by compiler
  >   with above settings, we found these settings are hard coded. So, this
  >   means simply add the above setting into web.config doesn’t affect a
  >   pre-compiled application. To make this taking affect, the application
  >   has to be re-compiled.
  >
  > [DebuggerNonUserCode]
  >
  > private void __BuildControlTree(default_aspx __ctrl)
  >
  > {
  >
  > ```
  > __ctrl.EnableViewStateMac = false;
  >
  > __ctrl.EnableEventValidation = false;
  > ```
  >
  > __ctrl.ViewStateEncryptionMode = ViewStateEncryptionMode.Never;
  >
  > This is a by-design behavior.

Comment: This was exactly how we deployed "pre-compiled ASP.Net application with updatable option disabled" and very likely was my issue. Never too late, thanks for the answer!